# How do I run a function without providing optional parameter

Tags: r

Suppose, I have a function called myfunction. How do I complete this function where if test2 is provided, I want to print "test2 is provided", if not, do nothing. I want to run the below function like `myfunction(test1)` without using `test2` (an optional parameter).

```
myfunction <- function (test1, test2){

do something...

if exists(test2){ print("test2 is provided")}

}
```

Comment: It gives alternative command to print "a" in the answer you mentioned, but I want to do nothing for a command associated with that parameter if not provided.

Comment: use `!missing()` rather than `exists()`.

Comment: Re-read the accepted answer.